# Android binding adapter doesn't change after property changed

Tags: android

I write a code for a simple dice roll app but there is a problem in updating the image of an image view that bound with a binding adapter
I can't extend BaseObservable class because I already extended the ViewModel class. I need that for keeping data after the status changed. Also, I can't observe the live data inside my binding adapter because the function is static

do you know any other way?

This is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.diceroller.MainActivityViewModel" />
</data>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:imageRes="@{viewModel.drawableResource}" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRoll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="Roll the dice"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onRollButtonClicked()}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is my kotlin code

```
class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() , Observable {

@Bindable
var drawableResource : MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData<Int>()

init {
    drawableResource.value = R.drawable.dice_1
}

fun onRollButtonClicked(){
    drawableResource.value = when(Random.nextInt(1,7)){
        1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
        2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
        3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
        4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
        5 -> R.drawable.dice_5
        else -> R.drawable.dice_6
    }

}

override fun addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback?) {

}

override fun removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback: 
Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback?) {
    }
}
@BindingAdapter("android:imageRes")
fun loadImage(view : View , imageRes : Int){
    (view as ImageView).setImageResource(imageRes)
}
```

Comment: This probably happens because you assign value after binding adapter called.  Looks like there is no need to make it like you do. Why you are not using android:src instead?

Comment: @AlexRmcf I tried that but the image will be empty! I don't know why

Comment: Oh I got what is the problem. You should do this -  android:imageRes="@{viewModel.drawableResource.value}", because integer image resource in your view model is named 'value'